# CSS: Absolute Positioning issue

Tags: css

I am trying to create a form of sorts with overlapping content. I created all the elements of the form, the idea is to position them `absolute` and `visible:hidden` and then use JS to toggle the visibility when buttons are clicked.
My issue is the when I apply `position:absolute` on any div, its will mess up the layout of the children in that `div`

Any fix?

```
 <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <form id="form-bizOwner">
                    <div class="container" id="B-firstQ">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center mb-3">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2 B-red-circle-div px-0">
                                        <div class="B-red-circle">01</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-8 B-input-field form-group">
                                        <label for="B-firstQ">Age</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="B-firstQ" min="18" placeholder="Enter your age">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 mt-4">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger px-5 py-2" id="B-firstNext">NEXT</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container"  id="B-secondQ">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center mb-3">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2 B-red-circle-div px-0">
                                        <div class="B-red-circle">02</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-10 B-input-field form-group">
                                        <label>Are you a business owner in Nigeria?</label>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input d-none" type="radio" name="B-secondQOptions" id="secondQYes" value="option1">
                                                    <label class="form-check-label btn btn-outline-info px-4" for="secondQYes">Yes</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input d-none" type="radio" name="B-secondQOptions" id="secondQNo" value="option2">
                                                    <label class="form-check-label btn btn-outline-info px-4" for="secondQNo">No</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 mt-4">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger px-5 py-2" id="B-secondNext">NEXT</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </form>
              </div>
```

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet?

Comment: I have inserted the snippet. It is a form of sorts